# In Laravel Mix, is it possible to extract all vendors except a list of packages?

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix, code-splitting-async

Normally in Laravel Mix, we can extract all vendors automatically using
`mix.extract()`
or extract a list of vendors using `mix.extract(['vue','lodash','axios'])`. Is there a way to extract all vendors except a few?

For example, I load Pusher, Echo, Chart.js, etc. when they're needed importing dynamic chunks. However, they're still getting added to my `vendor.js` file.

Also, when extracting a list of specific vendors, I end up with about 20 extra chunks due to sharing common code with names like `vendors~js/mychunk1~js/mychunk2~js/mychunk3`.

Comment: Same here. Also some code from my components goes to vendor and I have no idea about how to prevent that. Anyway my main issue is about the Intl package which I only use as a polyfill but is being served to all pages apparently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inserting a console.log in the Extract.js component inside Laravel Mix, I've found that in my current settings the plugin was just inserting these lines in the optimization field of the Webpack Configuration.

```js
optimization: {
  runtimeChunk: { name: '/js/manifest' },
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {},
    chunks: 'all',
    name: '/js/vendor',
  },
},
```

In order to filter what was going inside the vendor file I had to edit splitChunks like that:

```js
splitChunks: {
  cacheGroups: {
    vendor: {
      // moved name and chunks here
      name: 'js/vendor',
      chunks: 'all',
        // you can pass a RegExp to test, but also a function
        test(module/* , chunk */) {
          if (module.context) {
            // node_modules are needed
            const isNodeModule = module.context.includes('node_modules');
            // but only specific node_modules
            const nodesToBundle = [
             'vue',
             'lodash',
             'axios',
            ].some(str => module.context.includes(str));
            if (isNodeModule && nodesToBundle) {
              return true;
            }
         }
         return false;
       },
     }
  },
  // removed name and chunks from here  
  // chunks: 'all',
  // name: '/js/vendor',
},
```

After those changes I still had the weird naming you are experiencing, but thanks to this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/thatisuday/webpack-scp-demo) I discovered that I could remove this behavior by adding:

```js
default: false, // disable default groups
vendors: false, // disable vendors group
```

to the CacheGroups field.

So my complete webpackConfig function argument was:

```js
.webpackConfig({
  output: {
    // with other settings
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: { name: '/js/manifest' },
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        default: false,
        vendors: false,
        vendor: {
          name: 'js/vendor',
          chunks: 'all',
          // you can pass a RegExp to test, but also a function
          test(module/* , chunk */) {
            if (module.context) {
              // node_modules are needed
              const isNodeModule = module.context.includes('node_modules');
              // but only specific node_modules
              const nodesToBundle = [
                'vue',
                'lodash',
                'axios',
              ].some(str => module.context.includes(str));
              if (isNodeModule && nodesToBundle) {
                return true;
              }
           }
           return false;
         },
       }
     },
   },
 }
})
```

Be sure to also remove the extract() call in you mix file.

Answer (score 0):

**January 2022 Update**

From Laravel Mix v6 (released Dec 21, 2020), you can have multiple vendor files:

```
mix.extract(['vue','lodash','axios'], 'vendor-main.js');
mix.extract(); // everything else
```

These will be automatically loaded by webpack as needed.

You can also use the `webpack.IgnorePlugin` to specifically remove packages from the final build:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
mix.webpackConfig({
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {chunks: 'all'}
    },
    plugins: [
        // Ignore unnecessary package modules
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
            resourceRegExp: /^\.\/locale$/,
            contextRegExp: /moment$/,
        })
    ]
});
```